# Unexpected behavior in bash scripting on a ssh function

Tags: bash, apache-spark, hadoop, ssh, raspberry-pi

I've built a Raspberry pi cluster, with Spark and Hadoop installed, and have made a few functions in .bashrc to make communication and interaction a little easier

```
function otherpis {
grep "pi" /etc/hosts | awk '{print $2}' | grep -v $(hostname)
}

function clustercmd {
for pi in $(otherpis); do ssh $pi "$@"; done
$@
}
```

Where otherpis simply looks at the host file where i've precompiled all other raspberry pis in the cluster with their static ip addresses. I've also configured ssh with authorized keys so I don't have to enter a password everytime I ssh in.

I can call commands like

```
$ clustercmd date
Thu 03 Oct 2019 02:00:13 PM CDT
Thu 03 Oct 2019 02:00:11 PM CDT
Thu 03 Oct 2019 02:00:12 PM CDT
......
```

or

```
$ clustercmd sudo mkdir -p /opt/hadoop_tmp/hdfs
```

and it works just fine. But for some reason when I try to pass anything into the command with hadoop or spark, it says it can't find the command except for the pi that I'm invoking the command from.

```
$ clustercmd hadoop version | grep Hadoop
bash: hadoop: command not found
bash: hadoop: command not found
.....
Hadoop 3.2.1
```

But when I manually ssh into a pi and call the command, it works just fine.

```
$ ssh pi2
pi@pi2: $ hadoop version | grep Hadoop
Hadoop 3.2.1
```

I've exported all proper paths in .bashrc. I've **chown** of all relevant directories on each pi. No matter what I try, just the spark and hadoop commands aren't registering. Everything else is. I've even have a function that will do a file copy across the entire cluster

```
function clusterscp {
for pi in $(otherpis); do
cat $1 | ssh $pi "sudo tee $1" > /dev/null 2>&1
done
}
```

I setup hadoop and spark on the first pi, and then mass transferred all files and configurations with the above function with no problems. Any insight would help

**EDIT**
Adding all exported paths in .bashrc

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(readlink –f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:bin/java::")
export HADOOP_HOME=/opt/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin
export SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark
export PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin
export HADOOP_OPTS="-XX:-PrintWarnings –Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
export HADOOP_HOME_WARN_SUPPRESS=1
export HADOOP_ROOT_LOGGER="WARN,DRFA"
```

Note that as I stated earlier, when i'm actually SSH'd into the pi, all exported paths work fine, it is only when I try to run a **clustercmd** command that hadoop and spark is not found

## Solved

I fixed this by moving all exports above this line in the .bashrc

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
*i*);;
*) return;;
esac
```

And I added it to .profile in the home directory. This was originally suggested by mangusta, he just added a word to the file ".bash_profile", when it should be just "profile"

Answer (score 2):

`~/.bashrc` is executed when you have already logged in and want to open a new terminal window or execute a new shell instance.

If you login into machine (locally or remotely), what actually runs is `~/.bash_profile`, not `~/.bashrc`.

Try including you `HADOOP_HOME` and `SPARK_HOME` folders into `PATH` inside of `.bash_profile` on all your `pi_N` hosts

Comment: Should the .bash_profile already exist? I had to create one and entered in the exported paths, but it still doesn't work. I'm getting the same response

Comment: @MooseSims it shouldn't necessarily exist, you can create it manually. could you post the contents you have added into it?

Comment: I just copied and pasted the export paths as listed above in my OP

Comment: Also please see my comments I made below in the second response

Comment: @MooseSims did you create that file under `pi` account? note it should be placed into `pi` home directory (just like `.bashrc`)

Comment: Should I not ssh in, but physically logon to the pi and do it?

Comment: it doesn't matter, the important thing is it should be created under `pi`. anyway the issue is a bit strange. I will write my thoughts here if I find a clue to it

Comment: ah, my bad, actually this: `ssh $pi "$@"` is a non-login shell, which means that `.bashrc` is used, not `.bash_profile`.

Comment: I figured out the problem. You can see above the solution. You were close though. It is .profile, not .bash_profile. I still greatly appreciate the help however. It got me pointed in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

I think you can directly debug the problem reported by bash ("command not found") by running

```
echo $PATH
```

in the ssh shells on each RPi, and comparing the result with the result of

```
clustercmd 'echo $PATH'
```

Probably this will show that mangusta's answer is correct.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this. Unfortunately when I do this, it is showing the exported paths on all pis as exactly the same. My exported paths do exist as noted in the .bashrc. There's no difference in paths when I run this command on master vs when I run it via ssh

Comment: running this command locally -> /opt/hadoop/bin: /opt/hadoop/sbin:/opt/spark/bin                                        running this command in my clustercmd -> /opt/hadoop/bin:/opt/hadoop/sbin:/opt/spark/bin